# How do I tell HTML not to load the data with a group of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is the deal.  I am building html forms inside of an external application.  The issue is that the more html data I add the slower things get because it loads all of the html data in the dom.

This HTML data uses a angularjs controller that emits yet another controller (the main api's) and also uses services and directives from the main api as well.

My thought process is to create an iframe off of a menu you click and surround it with ng-if.  The issue is that the separate html page that is loaded in the iframe does not see the controllers data so none of the scopes work in the separate html pages.

I tried to create an ng-route, but that also does not seem to work because the page is always 'index.html' with iframes loading within the body of the html.

I tried using a ng-route (as seen in the code above), and also iframe (as seen in the code above) with separate pages.  I am looking for some ideas on how to load sections of the DOM only when the button is clicked.  My thought is to make each button click write to a scope, and then only load the data if that scope is equal to that value, but I believe it needs to be done in the iframe itself.

**HTML Section**

```
<div id="centricityEmrController" ng-controller="centricityEmrController" cemr-require-active-sdid>


<div id="top-level gmaController" ng-controller="gmaController"> 


<section>
TESTING TO SEE IF THIS SHOWS UP....
<br>
{{ iframeTest }}
</section>

</div> <!--top-level gmaController-->  
</div> <!--centricityEmrController-->
```

Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts to what can be done here?

**HTML Page**

```
<div>
  This is a TEST {{message}}
</div>
```

**JS Init**

```js
var APP_NAME = 'CentricityEmrExampleApp';
// Create the module
var myApp = angular.module(APP_NAME, ['centricityEmr', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/tabTest', {
    templateUrl: "/tabTest.html",
    controller: "gmaController"
  })
}]);

myApp.config(function(exceptionConfigProvider) {
  exceptionConfigProvider.config.formPrefix = 'HTML GMA LOG';
});

//Hides Possibly unhandled rejection error from clicking in md-selects when another dropdown is still open
myApp.config(['$qProvider', function($qProvider) {
  $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
function triggerUpdateTextTranslation() {
  // Get scope where the text translation method to trigger exists
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('textTransScope')).scope();
  if (scope.doTextTranslation) {
    scope.doTextTranslation();
  }
}
function showAlert() {
  alert("Basic Javascript alert!");
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// AngularJS Material Colors
myApp.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('cyan', {
      'default': '800',
      'hue-1': '500',
      'hue-2': '600',
      'hue-3': 'A100'
    })
    .accentPalette('cyan', {
      'default': '700'
    });
});
```

**Controller**
Please note I removed nearly all of the functions in the controller below it to make the example easier to digest.

```js
var myApp = angular.module(APP_NAME);

myApp.controller('gmaController', ['$rootScope', '$mdSidenav', '$mdMedia', '$http', '$scope', '$timeout', '$parse', '$compile', '$q', '$window', '$location', 'centricityEmrNativeFactory', 'centricityEmrNotificationFactory', 'centricityEmrWebServicesFactory',
  function($rootScope, $mdSidenav, $mdMedia, $http, $scope, $timeout, $parse, $compile, $q, $window, $location, centricityEmrNativeFactory, centricityEmrNotificationFactory, centricityEmrWebServicesFactory) {
    $rootScope.$emit("centricityEmrController", {});
    $scope.message = "Hello World";
  }
]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help